# Will storageClass kubernetes.io/no-provisioner work for multi-node cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, local-storage, kubeadm, kubernetes-pvc, kubernetes-statefulset

Cluster:
1 master 
2 workers

I am deploying StatefulSet using the local-volume using the PV (kubernetes.io/no-provisioner storageClass) with 3 replicas.
Created 2 PV for Both worker nodes.

Expectation: pods will be scheduled on both workers and sharing the same volume.

result: 3 stateful pods are created on single worker node. 
yaml :-

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-local-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: local-storage
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-pv-1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/vol1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - worker-node1 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-pv-2
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  # volumeMode field requires BlockVolume Alpha feature gate to be enabled.
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/vol2
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - worker-node2

---
# Headless service for stable DNS entries of StatefulSet members.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: test-headless
    port: 8000
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: test
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-service
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  ports:
  - name: test
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30063
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: test

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: test-stateful
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  serviceName: stateful-service
  replicas: 6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: container-1
        image: <Image-name>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: localvolume 
          mountPath: /tmp/
      volumes:
      - name: localvolume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: example-local-claim
```

Answer (score 4):

This happened because Kubernetes doesn't care about distribution. It has the mechanism for providing specific distribution called Pod Affinity.
For distributing pods on all workers, you may use [Pod Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity).
Furthermore, you can use soft affinity (the differences I [explain here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49427383/9485673) ), it isn't strict and allows to spawn all your pods. For example, StatefulSet will look like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  replicas: 3 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
        requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - my-app
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname      
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: app-name
        image: k8s.gcr.io/super-app:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 21
          name: web
```

This StatefulSet will try to spawn each pod on a new worker; if there are not enough workers, it will spawn the pod on the node where the pod already exists.

Comment: related to statefulset... with above configuration will the persistent volume(localstorage) "data" be replicated across all the worker nodes for the pod replicas ?? Does kubernetes StatefulSet handle that??

Comment: (probably too late) tl;dr is "no". data will not be replicated since 'local' PV type is supposed to work with storage attached to a specific node. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#local

Comment: @Abhishek, do we need to enable or do anything special 'local' provisioner to use that in a StorageClass(v1.14.8), I have similar requirement but referring to SC name instead of creating PV and it's not working?